# Как сделать чтобы картинка не обрезалась?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть слайдер и в нем картинки. Когда я растягиваю картинку по всей высоте и ширине, она обрезается сверху и снизу. Вот как ее растянуть без обрезаний? Или может есть еще какие то пути решения

```html
<div class="swiper-img"
                    style=
                    "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-image: url(&quot;./img/9R8A9185.jpg&quot;);
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: center center;
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%;
                    opacity: 1;
                    visibility: inherit;
                    z-index: 20;
                    object-fit: cover;
                    width: 2000px;"
                    src="./img/9R8A9185.jpg">
                </div>
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете что нам не видно вообще никакой картинки, потому что сюрприз, сюрприз, она у Вас находится локально.

Comment: background-size: contain; тогда не будет, но будут пустые поля

Comment: А почему вы для `<div>`'а указали атрибут `src`?